# Correct the error message when submitting with no tags in the android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, asking-questions, android-app

I just tried to submit a question, forgetting to add any tags and it told me "tags must be at least 2 characters".

I think it should tell me I need to add tags, not that a nonexistent one is too short.

Comment: I guess a non-existent tag is too short though!

Comment: Yes error message should be informative. Tags must be at least 2 characters is not conveying anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages will be a bit more helpful in the next release.